# create a .csv file for submission

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, cnn, image-classification

I am trying to make a submission of a multiclass image classificaition problem, in which I have images belonging to four different classes which are four different weather conditions: HAZE, SUNNY, SNOWY, RAINY. What I would like to have is a .csv file of the following structure:

> image ID, prediction

so for example something like:

> 0000,HAZE
>
> 0001,SUNNY
>
> 0002,SUNNY
>
> 0003,RAINY
>
> 0004,SNOWY

and so on. I am really struggling to do this. I have a blind test set which contains images of these weathers, but with no labels, and so the point of the .csv file is to assign to each of this image a label and write everything on a csv as said.

Until now, i have made the predictions on the blind test set in the following way:

```
blind_testSet = '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/submission'

test_datagen_blind = ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center=True,
    featurewise_std_normalization=True,
    rescale = 1. / 255
   )


test_generator_blind = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory=blind_testSet,
    target_size=(256, 256),
    color_mode="rgb",
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode="categorical",
    shuffle=False
)

preds = transfer_model.predict_generator(test_generator_blind,verbose=1,steps=val_steps)
```

but if I look at how preds is made, I see that it contains a set of probabilities:

[image]

and do I don't know how to do this .csv file. Just to be clearer, the structure I would like to have is something similar to this:

[image]

which is an image I found on the internet, but it is the result I would like to achieve.

Can somebody please help me building this csv file? Thanks in advance.

[EDIT]I am trying to do the following:

```
import pandas as pd

predicted_class_indices=np.argmax(preds,axis=1)
labels = (test_generator_blind.class_indices)
labels = dict((v,k) for k,v in labels.items())
predictions = [labels[k] for k in predicted_class_indices]
```

but if I run the code at this point I recieve the error message:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-e694ed25560e> in <module>()
      4 labels = (test_generator_blind.class_indices)
      5 labels = dict((v,k) for k,v in labels.items())
----> 6 predictions = [labels[k] for k in predicted_class_indices]

<ipython-input-31-e694ed25560e> in <listcomp>(.0)
      4 labels = (test_generator_blind.class_indices)
      5 labels = dict((v,k) for k,v in labels.items())
----> 6 predictions = [labels[k] for k in predicted_class_indices]

KeyError: 3
```

Am I going towards the right direction? And why do I get this error? Thanks.

[EDIT]The complete code is the following:

```
import pandas as pd

predicted_class_indices=np.argmax(preds,axis=1)
labels = (test_generator_blind.class_indices)
labels = dict((v,k) for k,v in labels.items())
predictions = [labels[k] for k in predicted_class_indices]
filenames=test_generator_blind.filenames
results=pd.DataFrame({"image ID":filenames,
                  "Predictions":preds})
results.to_csv("submission.csv",index=False)
```

[EDIT]I think the problem is the following line:

```
labels = (test_generator_blind.class_indices)
```

infact, if I do

```
predicted_class_indices=np.argmax(preds,axis=1)
labels = (test_generator_blind.class_indices)
print(labels)
```

I get as output:

```
{'blind_testset': 0}
```

[EDIT]Ok I am still working in this and I have that if I do `print(predicted_class_indices)` I get :

```
[0 3 3 1 3 1 0 1 1 0 1 2 1 3 0 1 0 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 3 3 1 1 2 3 3 2 1 2 0 2 3
 1 2 2 1 3 2 1 2 2 2 0 0 1 2 0 0 0 1 3 3 2 0 2 3 1 2 3 3 1 3 2 1 0 3 0 1 1
 2 1 3 2 0 2 1 3 3 3 3 2 0 1 1 3 1 3 3 3 1 2 3 2 1 3 1 0 0 1 1 0 3 0 0 1 0
 2 3 2 1 1 3 1 2 0 2 2 2 3 1 1 2 0 3 3 0 3 0 1 2 0 3 0 2 2 2 0 3 2 0 2 1 1
 1 3 3 0 1 1 2 0 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 1 3 0 3 0 1 3 1 1 3 2 2 2 0 3 3 0 3 0 0
 0 3 2 2 2 2 3 1 3 2 3 2 2 2 0 0 2 1 1 0 2 0 3 3 1 3 3 2 0 1 1 3 3 2 2 2 0
 0 1 3 2 2 1 1 3 0 2 1 2 1 2 1 3 2 3 0 1 2 2 1 0 1 0 3 2 2 2 0 2 0 3 0 2 1
 2 1 2 2 1 2 0 2 0 3 0 0 1 2 0 2 3 1 1 2 2 1 3 0 3 3 1 0 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 0 0
 2 2 2 0 0 2 3 0 3 0 0 0 1 2 3 2 3 0 1 1 2 1 0 3 0 1 0 2 1 2 3 0 1 0 3 1 1
 2 2 0 1 3 1 0 0 3 1 1 2 2 1 3 2 3 1 0 3 0 0 3 0 2 1 3 3 2 2 2 3 0 3 2 3 2
 2 0 2 0 3 2 2 3 3 3 2 0 1 0 2 0 0 0 2 1 2 1 0 2 2 3 3 0 3 3 1 0 3 2 2 1 3
 2 2 0 3 2 3 3 3 2 1 3 0 0 1 3 3 3 2 0 1 0 2 0 1 3 0 1 0 0 1 3 0 0 2 2 1 1
 2 3 3 3 2 2 2 0 3 3 2 2 0 2 2 2 3 3 1 2 1 3 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 3 1 2 1 2 1 3
 2 3 1 3 2 2 0 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 2 2 2 3 2 3 2 0 1 0 0 0 3 3 2 1 1 3 3 3 2 1 3
 3 3 0 1 2 3 0 3 0 1 2 0 3 1 0 3 1 3 0 1 1 0 3 0 3 2 3 1 2 2 0 3 0 2 2 1 3
 1 0 2 2 2 3 2 0 0 0 1 2 1 3 0 3 1 1 2 2 1 3 3 2 2 0 3 2 0 2 1 0 2 1 2 3 2
 3 3 2 2 3 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 3 2 3 3 2 2 0 2 3 2 0 3 2 1 0 2 0 1 0 3 0 2 3 3 3
 2 2 2 0 2 2 2 1 0 3 1 1 2 0 1 1 1 0 3 0 0 0 1 3 2 2 0 2 0 0 3 1 2 3 2 2 1
 1 0 3 0 2 0 2 3 1 0 1 3 0 0 0 3 2 1 2 0 2 3 2 0 1 2 3 0 1 1 0 2 2 1 2 0 0
 0 3 0 2 3 1 0 2 3 0 1 1 2 1 3 3 0 0 1 3 1 3 2 0 0 1 0 1 2 3 2 2 3 1 0 2 0
 3 2 1 0 3 2 3 0 2 2 0 2 2 0 0 2 2 3 3 3 2 3 3 0 0 2 1 0 1 2 2 2 1 2 0 2 1
 0 0 0 2 2 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 2 3 1 0 1 1 3 2 3 0 2 2 2 2 2 1 1]
```

which should be what I expected. So the problem is the line after this, but I really don't undesrstand what i am doing wrong.

[EDIT_4] This post is getting long, but I am consatntly working on this. I think I have solved the avove issue, so now my code is :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

predicted_class_indices=np.argmax(preds,axis=1)
labels = (train_generator.class_indices)
labels = dict((v,k) for k,v in labels.items())
print(labels)
predictions = [labels[k] for k in predicted_class_indices]
filenames=test_generator_blind.filenames
results=pd.DataFrame({"image ID":filenames,
                  "Predictions":preds})
results.to_csv("submission.csv",index=False)
```

but now I get the error message:

```
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-37b4cd72c225> in <module>()
     9 filenames=test_generator_blind.filenames
     10 results=pd.DataFrame({"image ID":filenames,
---> 11                       "Predictions":preds})
     12 results.to_csv("submission.csv",index=False)

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py in 
sanitize_array(data, index, dtype, copy, raise_cast_failure)
    727     elif subarr.ndim > 1:
    728         if isinstance(data, np.ndarray):
--> 729             raise Exception("Data must be 1-dimensional")
    730         else:
    731             subarr = com.asarray_tuplesafe(data, dtype=dtype)

Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional
```

can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Your approach seems correct, it seems to be just a coding question. Have you tried printing your `labels` variables? I'm suspecting the keys to be string type. If this is the problem, just change the previous line into: `labels = dict((int(v),k) for k,v in labels.items())`

Comment: Thanks for answering. What I would like to do is to map the predicted labels with their ID. I will edit my question with what I want to do next.

Comment: @RomainReboulleau, I changed the line as you suggested, but I still get the same error. Thanks again.

Comment: Try to print the `labels` dictionary, this will surely help.

Comment: if I do print(labels) I get as output {0: 'blind_testset'}. So yes the problem is there for sure.

Comment: Actually I think the problem is in this line: labels = (test_generator_blind.class_indices) since if I do print(labels) here I get {'blind_testset': 0}

Comment: I think I have overcomed this proble by considering the train_generator, which I defined in another part of the code,  for defining labels. Now I have the exception Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional which is driving me crazy.

Comment: try replacing `preds` by `preds.ravel()`